# Windows XP Logo Testing

Tags: testing

I’m trying to get a point-of-sale PC computer logo certified and while running DTM Studio v1.4.7100.017, the only option I get under 'Create New Submission'->'Windows XP' o/s->System Submission is ‘*Netbook (ULPC)*'.

[Microsoft here states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd424513.aspx):

> On Windows XP, DTM supports the
>   following system test categories:
>   • Desktop
>
> • Mobile
>
> • Motherboard

How can I perform ‘**Desktop system**’ testing using my DTM setup when I don’t get the option?

Vista, Windows 7, etc. display such options when I select them.  But Windows XP is empty of such choices.  I really need to perform a 'System Submission', not 'device submission'.

Thanks for any input.   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that Microsoft has been trying to end the support cycle for Windows XP. We are currently in the opening stages of the Windows 7 support life cycle, and mid-cycle for Windows Vista.

If you look at the [licensing / life cycle roadmap](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/lifecycle/default.mspx), you will see that (aside from Netbook/ULPC) Microsoft no longer makes Windows XP available to system builders -- they ended that January 31, 2009.

While I understand that XP is a desirable choice for many custom builds, currently your licensing choices are Vista and 7. The exception to this *may* be Windows XP Embedded -- which appears to have mainstream support ending in 2011. I do not know of its availability, however. (The Embedded program is a very different beast from standard system builds.)

Comment: Looks like I'll be making a call to the Microsoft Test Group then regarding my special case.  Because MS is still supporting XP through security updates, and it won't disappear overnight.  Even if they would like it to.